# bing map- 2 pushpins same co-ordinate workaround?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, pushpin

I have multiple locations that I show on the bing map via pushpins at specific lat/long co-ordinates. There's a situation where 2 pushpins have the same co-ordinates and both are stacked on top of each other. So the user cannot click or see the pushpin below. Please suggest workarounds or any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to display some sort of cluster icon to let the user see that there is more than one location represented by that pushpin, and then present a disambiguation box when the user clicks/hovers on the pushpin to let them choose which location they want to select.
This is the same approach as you would use to cluster pushpin data on the map - aggregating several distinct items of data into a single cluster unit.